# Reposting via Soundcloud Python API

Tags: soundcloud

Is there any way to repost a track via the Soundcloud Python API? I am having a bit of trouble. I tried client.put('/me/track_reposts/trackID') but it gave me a 404 error. Did anybody have better luck?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
client.put('/e1/me/track_reposts/'+str(track.id))
```

It's that little 'e1' at the beginning that got me for the longest time.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use post or put? Try put.

Ex.

Reposting

PUT https://api.soundcloud.com/me/track_reposts/159642137?client_id=b45b_

Removing Reposting

DELETE https://api.soundcloud.com/me/track_reposts/159642137?client_id=b45b_